# MVC 4 Application with Sharepoint 2013 used for file storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint

We are currently starting to plan out an MVC 4 application that has some file management capabilities.  We outsourced a firm to help with architecture considerations and their recommendation was to use SharePoint for our file storage needs.

My question is has anyone used this approach and what worked and didn't work very well?  Also how did you handle users between the two applications?  We do not want to use active directory for authentication and a user repository.

Comment: SharePoint is a nuclear reactor. The entry cost is high. What is exactly your requirement regarding "file storage"? If you only have to store and serve document, SharePoint will be an overkill and an overcost. If you need collaborative capabilities, then SharePoint may be a good choice. Just don't expect to integrage it easily from an MVC app.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  We are only storing and accessing the files and providing management of files to the users with versioning, etc through the application.  There will be financial data included with the documents so a solution such as Amazon or Azure we ruled out as we would like more control and protection of the files.

Comment: You may study the architectural consideration of a SharePoint farm. This is a not a simple application, but a whole platform with its requirement. If there is already a SharePoint farm setup somewhere which you can rely on. Give it a try. IF you have to set up sharepoint just for this need, forget it. This will be complex and costly (both in term of day to code and licences). I don't know what is your current backend, but did you ever look at Sql Server Filestream capabilities? it may help to works efficiently with files within Sql Server.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a look.  This is a new application going on new infrastructure so I am trying to verify recommendations now and thought SharePoint might have been overkill so wanted to verify with some other that might have used it.  That is looking to be the case and I will look for other options including building the file management piece ourselves.

Comment: Did you ever end up using Sharepoint as a back-end file store? We are considering the same architecture (MVC3/4 apps with SP2013) and would love to hear how your project turned out.